# How to add camera brand or model in exif meta?

Tags: camera

In my android mobile there is no  camera brand or model in exif meta  but rest of the exif tags are ok. how can i fix this?

Model :Xstreamer Aiki 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use apps like [EXIF Tag Editor (Photo)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teapps.exiftageditor) and [Pixelgarde](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixelgarde.free) to view/edit EXIF data of your images. Both apps has the ability to batch-process the images.

If you are looking for a way to automatically add information (particularly the *camera model* as in your question), you cannot do anything rather than waiting for an update from your device manufacturer. This is because embedding that information is configured the the ROM itself.

Comment: I am looking for option in ROM like build.prop changing config files etc. (My Mobile rooted)

Comment: @Sridher, If you are looking for a development option, you might get better answers in [so].